# How do you use std::not1 and std::not2?

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently if you want to negate a predicate, you have to use a `std::<algorithm>_if_not` variant or a lambda. But for the sake of academics I want to know if this is possible:

```
std::string s("hello");
std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::not1(::ispunct));
```

Without writing my own function object, how to make this code work?

Comment: With the Library Fundamentals v2 TS, `std::not_fn(::ispunct)`. Note, however, that in order for this call to be safe for any string, the characters should be converted to `unsigned char` before being passed into `ispunct`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that the correct way to pass `char`s to the character classification functions (along with `toupper` and `tolower`) that came from the C standard library is to convert it first to `unsigned char` and then to `int`.

Using `std::ref` and a `reference_wrapper` for this is lightweight, and wrong. Using `std::function<bool(int)>` or `std::function<bool(char)>` are more heavyweight, and also wrong. In all those cases the `char` in the string is directly converted to `int`, which is not the right way to do it.

If you insist on not using a lambda, then

```
std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::not1(std::function<bool(unsigned char)>(::ispunct)));
```

is one right way to do it. Otherwise

```
std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return !ispunct(c); });
```

is easier to understand - and shorter.

Comment: Could you explain or provide references for your first sentence?

Comment: @Pradhan These functions are defined in the C standard. WG14 N1570 §7.4 - "The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 4):

> The unary predicate type must define a member type, `argument_type`, that is convertible to the predicate's parameter type.

The most lightweight way to wrap `::ispunct` is to use `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::not1(std::ref(::ispunct)));
                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

One of approaches is to use `std::reference_wrapper` . Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "...hello" );

    auto it = std::find_if( s.begin(), s.end(), std::not1( std::ref( ::ispunct ) ) );

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
h
```