# Negate a lambda without knowing the argument type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, lambda

I'm trying to write an in-place filter function that works similarly to Python's filter. For example:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
filter_ip(x, [](const int& i) { return i >= 3; });
// x is now {3, 4, 5}
```

First I tried this:

```
template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter_ip(Container& c, Filter&& f)
{
  c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), std::not1(f)), c.end());
}
```

However, that doesn't work because lambdas [don't have an `argument_type` field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1).

This following variant [does work](https://ideone.com/qlTD1y):

```
template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter_ip(Container& c, Filter&& f)
{
  c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), 
                         [&f](const typename Container::value_type& x) { 
                            return !f(x); 
                         }), 
          c.end());
}
```

However, it seems less than ideal because before, it would only have required that `Container` have `begin`, `end`, and `erase`, while now it also requires that it defines a `value_type`. Plus it looks a little unwieldy.

This is the 2nd approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29239271/15055). The first would use `std::not1(std::function<bool(const typename Container::value_type&)>(f))` instead of the lambda, which still requires the type.

I also tried specifying the arg func as an `std::function` with a known argument type:

```
template <typename Container, typename Arg>
void filter_ip(Container& c, std::function<bool(const Arg&)>&& f)
{
  c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), std::not1(f)), c.end());
}
```

But then I get:

```
'main()::<lambda(const int&)>' is not derived from 'std::function<bool(const Arg&)>'
```

Is there any way around this? Intuitively it seems it should be really simple since all you need to do is apply a not to a bool which you already know `f` returns.

Comment: C++14 has generic lambdas. They'd fit in nicely.

Comment: [`std::experimental::not_fn`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4076.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if you already require a `begin`, `end`, and `erase`, also requiring a `value_type` is a pretty minor addition. If you could get away from requiring `erase`, that would gain you at least a few real containers, but eliminating a requirement for `value_type` doesn't accomplish much.

Nonetheless, in case you had a container that really did define `erase`, but not `value_type`, you could side-step the requirement for it to define `value_type` directly by getting the value_type from the iterator:

```
template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter_ip(Container& c, Filter&& f) {
    using It = decltype(c.begin());

    c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(),
        [&f](const std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type& x) {
        return !f(x);
    }),
        c.end());
}
```

Using `iterator_traits<T>::value_type`, you can (for example) get the pointee type when the iterator is really a pointer. I don't know of any practical advantage in this case though when you already require `begin()`, `end()` and (especially) `erase`. We could eliminate the requirement for `begin()` and `end()` as members by using `std::begin(c)` and `std::end(c)`, but (again) that doesn't really gain us anything meaningful (like the ability to work with arrays) when we still need an `erase` member.

An even simpler approach would be to use `std::partition` instead:

```
template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter_ip(Container& c, Filter&& f) {
    c.erase(std::partition(c.begin(), c.end(), f), c.end());
}
```

This does have the disadvantage that it can (will) rearrange the elements that it keeps, so it won't work if you really need to retain the original order. This could also be less efficient if copy/move construction is much less expensive than swapping (but that's fairly uncommon).

One final possibility would be to just implement the algorithm on your own instead of delegating to another algorithm:

```
template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter2(Container& c, Filter&& f) {
    auto dst = c.begin();

    for (auto src = dst; src != c.end(); ++src)
        if (f(*src)) {
            *dst = *src;
            ++dst;
        }
    c.erase(dst, c.end());
}
```

If you prefer to avoid self-assignment, you could add:

```
while (f(*dst))
    ++dst;
```

...before the `for` loop above.

Comment: Very sensible, sir. I reasoned similarly when figuring out whether it would work for arrays - that arrays don't have an `erase` method, that is. I'll probably just rely on `value_type`, but if I didn't, I like the `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` approach the most.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use C++14 generic lambdas, how about delegating to a classic functor with a templated `operator()` :

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class F>
struct negate {
    negate(F&& f)
    : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

    template <class... Args>
    bool operator () (Args &&... args) {
        return !_f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    F _f;
};

template <typename Container, typename Filter>
void filter_ip(Container& c, Filter&& f)
{
    c.erase(std::remove_if(
        c.begin(),
        c.end(),
        negate<Filter>(std::forward<Filter>(f))),
        c.end()
    );
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    filter_ip(v, [](int i) {return bool(i%2);});
    for(auto &&i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output :

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48aaccae4e231b79)

Comment: It might be better to deduce the return type for `operator()` to allow detection of *is callable* via SFINAE. Additionally, `negate` might not be the best name since `std::negate` uses unary `-` (minus), not `!` (logical not). -- Oh, and it is customary to add a factory function template for type deduction.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class F>
struct not_f_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Ts>
  decltype(!std::declval<typename std::result_of<F&(Ts...)>::type>())
  operator()(Ts&&...ts) {
    return !f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};
template<class F, class dF=typename std::decay<F>::type>
not_f_t<dF> not_f(F&& f){
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

or in C++14, we can dispense with the `not_f_t` class and do:

```
template<class F,class dF=std::decay_t<F>>// dF optional
auto not_f(F&& f){
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable
  ->decltype(!std::declval<std::result_of_t<dF&(decltype(args)...)>>()) // optional, adds sfinae
  {
    return !f(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

and then, because it rocks:

```
template<class C, class F>
void erase_remove_if( C&& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  c.erase( std::remove_if( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) ), end(c) );
}
```

we get:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
erase_remove_if(x, not_f([](int i){return i>=3;}));
```

Comment: The polymorphic lambda lacks the SFINAE-friendliness of `not_f_t::operator()`. (You know that of course, but not everyone might know.)

Comment: @dyp *nod*: 1 line added and 1 line modified to add sfinae support for 14.  Still briefer.

Comment: o.O If my eyes don't deceive me, you're missing the `!` in `not_f_t`. Also, it might be slightly more appropriate to include the `!` in the determination of the return type. One example that comes to mind is a function that returns a pointer (say, an iterator), which can be adapted via `!` to become a predicate. OTOH, restricting `not_f` to operate on predicates only might be more reasonable.

Comment: Agreed @dyp, but that sure makes the sfinae ugly.  Makes me want to have `struct not_t` to make it simpler.  And a smart, recursive `result_of` maybe.

Comment: Indeed, it's now even longer than the repeated `decltype(!f(..))` Any reason to prefer `result_of_t` if it's not shorter than the repetition of the return expression?

Comment: @dyp I don't know off by heart the rules if/when captured variables can be used in the return type deduction of a lambda `()`.  I know that there are sometimes quirky rules involving class member variables.  In short, I'm lazy and don't want to test something I don't know if it would work?  In real code, I'd write my recursive `result` and do `result2< bang(F&(decltype(args)...)) >`, where `bang` is a function object that does `!` on its input.  Call it decltype prejudice.